# Weird problem with doing tests with junit

Tags: java, junit, tdd

I'm writing a little library for movies for myself. It's partly for learning TDD. Now I have a problem I can't solve.

The code is in here https://github.com/hasanen/MovieLibrary/blob/master/movielibrary-core/src/test/java/net/pieceofcode/movielibrary/service/MovieLibraryServiceITC.java

The problem is that when I run the whole class (right click above class name in eclipse), the second test fails because removing doesn't succeed. But when right clicking the method (getMovieGenres_getAllGenresAndRemoveOne_returnsTwoGenreAndIdsAreDifferent) and choosing Run as Junit Test, it works.

I don't necessarily need the fix, but at least some advice on how to find why junit is acting like this.

Comment: The movieLibraryService variable is annotated @Resource - what is injecting the value into that variable?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand this one. I'm using https://github.com/hasanen/MovieLibrary/blob/master/movielibrary-core/src/test/java/net/pieceofcode/movielibrary/ITCBase.java at the base of all integration test. So if I understanded your question right the answer is spring? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the way you explain the problem, the problem appears to be in the setUp class. The setUp class runs before every test case invocation. This is the general sequence.

1- Add three movies.

2- Test if three movies exists.

3- Add three movies

4- remove movie item # 1.

Since sequence 1-4 works, the problem is sequence 3. Either sequence 3 swallows some exception or mutates the underlying object. (may be changes the sequence.) Without knowing how addMovie changes the underlying object, its hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks, I solve the problem. I didn't consider that when the second test the id's of genres wasn't 0,1,3 as those were in first test. So I made new method which gives me genre by title so I don't need to hard code the id when I'm testing removing.

Comment: That may solve this instance of the issue, but it's not the best tactic.  See my answer.

Comment: I agree with @Don.. Please create a new instance in the setup method.

Answer (score 0):

Something outside your test class (likely a superclass) is creating `movieLibraryService`, and it's not being recreated as often as it needs to be for independent testing.

If you add the line

```
movieLibraryService = new MovieLibraryService();
```

at the top of your `testSetUp()` method, this service will be properly reset before the running of each test method, and they will likely work properly.

As it is, I suspect you're getting a failure on the assertions about size, as the size is becoming 6 instead of 3.

Alternatively, you could add a teardown method (annotated with `@After`) which removes the contents of the movie library so that it always starts empty.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the problem is your test isn't real unit test but integration one. So while testing your service you're testing all the layers it uses. I recommend yo to use mocks for lower layers dependencies (EasyMock or something) and use integration tests only for your repository layer. This way you can avoid persistence layer influences while testing service layer.